# How pensions work for a French person working in Japan

Tags: pension, japan, french-citizens

After working for 4 years in France, I have been working for 6 years already in Japan (both as a full-time employee).

How do pensions work in that case?
Do years in France and years in Japan get counted automatically, or do I have to do something special?

Comment: A few links on this topic: https://www.lassuranceretraite.fr/cs/Satellite/PUBPrincipale/SalariesPlus55/Droits-Cas-Par-Cas-Salaries55/En-Cas-Activites-France-Etranger55?packedargs=null and http://www.cleiss.fr/docs/textes/conv_japon.html

Answer (score 2):

[The Agreement between Japan and France on Social Security](http://www.mofa.go.jp/announce/announce/2007/4/1173013_824.html)

According to above article, if you paid pension in both countries they will be added together.

Comment: can you include some more details from the linked website into the answer

Comment: As for his question, no, they will probably not added together automatically. You have to apply for it. Here are a bunch of documents available in PDF format for download:
http://www.nenkin.go.jp/n/www/agreement/detail.jsp?id=1021

I think the easiest way is to give Embassy of France a call and ask them directly.